# Link image with data from the wpdb

Tags: database, post-meta

It might be a stupid question, but I can't get it to work..

**Problem**
I have no idea how to link my image on the frontend with the url from the database.

**Situation**
I've created a Custom Post Type called 'Banners'. On each post I'm able to add a featured image. This will be saved in my database. Also on each post edit page, there is a input area for the banner_url. There I give my banner the link where it should go after clicking on it on the frontend. I'm able now to display the image I want on the page I want. But now I need to get the url out off the database and connent it to my image.

**Code**

```
<?php
// function to show home page banner using query of banner post type
function wptutsplus_home_page_banner() {

// start by setting up the query
$get_banner = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'banners',
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'banner_link',
        'value' => 'https://www.mypage.com'
      )
    )
));

// now check if the query has posts and if so, output their content in a banner-box div
if ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <?php while ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : $get_banner->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="container" align="center"><a href=""><?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

**Question**
My question is: How do I get the banner_url out of the database? And how am I able to get it to work with the image?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT PROBLEM SOLVED**
Thanks to Abdul Awal

```
<?php
// function to show home page banner using query of banner post type
function wptutsplus_home_page_banner() {

// start by setting up the query
 $get_banner = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'banners',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'banner_link',
      'value' => 'https://www.mypage.com'
    )
  )
));

// now check if the query has posts and if so, output their content in a banner-box div
if ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : while ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : $get_banner->the_post();

$output = '<div class="container" align="center"><a href="'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'banner_link', true ).'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</a></div>';

endwhile;
endif;
 wp_reset_postdata();
return $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to query only the items that has `banner_link` value set to `https://www.mypage.com` ?

If no, you can remove the `meta_query` part from your query.

```
<?php
// function to show home page banner using query of banner post type
function wptutsplus_home_page_banner() {

// start by setting up the query
$get_banner = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'banners',
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'banner_link',
        'value' => 'https://www.mypage.com'
      )
    )
));

// now check if the query has posts and if so, output their content in a banner-box div
if ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <?php while ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : $get_banner->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="container" align="center"><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'banner_link', true ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

As you're using it inside a plugin. You can do like the following:

```
<?php
// function to show home page banner using query of banner post type
function wptutsplus_home_page_banner() {

// start by setting up the query
$get_banner = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'banners',
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'banner_link',
        'value' => 'https://www.mypage.com'
      )
    )
));

// now check if the query has posts and if so, output their content in a banner-box div
if ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : while ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : $get_banner->the_post();

  $output = '<div class="container" align="center"><a href="'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'banner_link', true ).'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</a></div>';

endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
return $output;
}
?>
```

And then call it anywhere with `<?php echo wptutsplus_home_page_banner(); ?>`

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, because I've got more banners but with another meta_value.

Comment: Ok. It should work for you then. Have you tried the code ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It only refresh the page. Maybe it's because the post_id is different because the function is in my pluginfolder. And where I call the function and want to display the image, is in my theme folder?

Comment: Edited answer. Please try with the newly added code.

Comment: Image is displayed also, but the link doesn't work either. I have no clue at all what is wrong :(

Comment: Can you try replacing `$post->ID` to `get_the_ID()` ?

Comment: Nice, it's working. Thank you so much, really appreciated!

Comment: Great to know that its working :)

Comment: Can you please take a look over here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260985/need-help-with-do-shortcode-based-on-thumbnail-id, I have a new problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `get_post_meta()`

Your loop should look like:

```
<?php while ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : $get_banner->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="container" align="center"><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'banner_link', true); ?>"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: Thanks for your time! Will be appreciated but it doesn't work. This function is in my plugin file, and on another .php file in my theme folder I call the function. So maybe the get_the_ID() is not correct? And the banner_link is the meta_key but I need the meta_value from the banner_link.

Comment: Since you're already in a loop try just `$post->ID` instead of `get_the_ID()`. `echo get_post_meta` should spit out the meta_value you need.

Comment: Hi Elaine, I've already tried it, but it won't work. It will only refresh the page..

Comment: Are you sure the meta field have this name `banner_link` ? You may try do a `var_dump(get_post_custom(get_the_ID());` to see all the meta fields saved in the post