# do_shortcode based on _thumbnail_id

Tags: shortcode, database, post-meta

**Situation**
I've created a Custom Post Type called 'Banners'. On each post I'm able to add a featured image. This will be saved in my database and will get an **_thumbnail_id**. Also on each post edit page, there is a custom meta box for the banner_url and the target attribute. There I give my banner the link where it should go after clicking on it on the frontend. And the target attribute will open the image in the correct way. This will be correctly send to my wpdb.

Plugin code:

```
<?php
// function to show a banner using query of banner post type
function show_banner() {

// start by setting up the query
$get_banner = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'banners',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'key' => 'banner_link',
      'value' => 'https://www.mypage.com'
    )
  )
));


// now check if the query has posts and if so, output their content in a banner-box div
if ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : while ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : $get_banner->the_post();

$output = '<div class="container" align="center"><a href="'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'banner_link', true ).'"
target="'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'target', true).'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</a></div>';

 endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'banner', 'show_banner' );
//END
?>
```

Page.php

```
<?php  echo do_shortcode("[banner]");?>
```

**Question**
I use a meta_query to select the url. It works perfectly and displays the correct image. Also the link and target works fine. But what I want is that
I can add a thumbnail_id to the do_shortcode echo and then the correct image is displayed on the frontend with the right url and target around it.

I hope someone can help me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT SOLUTION**
Managed to fix the problem
Special thanks to bynicolas for getting me in the right direction!

Plugin code:

```
<?php
// function to show a banner using query of banner post type
function show_banner( $att ) {

  // Set default $att values if none is provided
  // $att is an array so access the shortcode value via     $att['thumbnail_id']
  // in the [banner thumbnail_id="12"] shortcode

$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        '_thumbnail_id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'banner' );

//print_r('Thumbnail_id: ' . $att['_thumbnail_id'] . '<br>');

//start by setting up the query
$get_banner = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'banners',
)
);

//now check if the query has posts and if so, output their content in a banner-box div
if ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : $get_banner->the_post();

    $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_thumbnail_id', true);
    $image_url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'banner_link', true);
    $target = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'target', true);

    if ($thumbnail_id === $att['_thumbnail_id']) {
      // print_r($thumbnail_id . ' ');
      // print_r($image_url . ' ');
      // print_r($target . '<br>');
      $output = '<div class="container" align="center"><a href="'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'banner_link', true ).'"
      target="'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'target', true).'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().
      '</a></div>';
    }

  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'banner', 'show_banner' );
?>
```

Page.php

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[banner _thumbnail_id="584"]');?>
//584 is the thumbnail_id, so change that to your own thumbnail_id.
```

Comment: is the code `//start by setting the query` is your `show_banner` function?

Comment: Oops my bad, did edit my code.

Comment: ok, you can pass an `$att` argument to that function containing additional custom value to that shortcode... I'll write an example up if that is what you want

Comment: Yeah, what I want is when I need the image with thumnail_id=573 to be displayed, just echo: <?php echo do_shortcode("[banner _thumbnail_id='573']");?> for example

Answer (score 0):

```
// function to show a banner using query of banner post type
function show_banner( $att ) {

  // Set default $att values if none is provided
  // $att is an array so access the shortcode value via $att['thumbnail_id']
  // in the [banner thumbnail_id="12"] shortcode
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'thumbnail_id' => '',
  ), $atts, 'banner' );

  // start by setting up the query
  $get_banner = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'banners',
    'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'banner_link',
        'value' => 'https://www.mypage.com'
      )
    )
  ));


  $img_markup = ! empty( $att[ 'thumbnail_id' ] ) ? sprintf( '<img src="%s" />', wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att[ 'thumbnail_id' ] ) ) : '';


  // now check if the query has posts and if so, output their content in a banner-box div
  if ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $get_banner->have_posts() ) : $get_banner->the_post();

      $output = '<div class="container" align="center"><a href="'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'banner_link', true ).'"
      target="'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'target', true).'">'.$img_markup.'</a></div>';

    endwhile;
  endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'banner', 'show_banner' );
```

Comment: First thanks your your time. But it doesn't work. Right now my image is selected by the meta_query. So if I change the value to some other url, I will get another image. The point right now is that the code must change so, that when I say I want the image with id: 123 in the shortcode, the image 123 is displayed. With mine and your edited code, I will always get the image linked to https://www.mypage.com. I hope your understand what I need to achieve. Appreciate your suggetion!

Comment: well it's because I didn't finish the code to achieve that. I just added what was needed to grab the image id from the shortcode... so if I get this correctly, if you pass an image id to the shortcode, you want that image to be displayed, if not, you want the image from the query to be displayed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But if not, I don't want any image to display. An image only need to displayed when I pass an image id to the shortcode.

Comment: ok let me edit that real quick

Comment: done, but I think it still misses something... if you don't have an image id, what are you supposed to show, just the link to the banner? because now if there is no image id, we are missing some link anchor!

Comment: Yeah, you still missing something. Did you read my situation in the beginning? I add in my CPT a new banner through a featured image (with a banner_link and target in a custom meta box) and send this to my database. There it will get an thumbnail_id. Then on my page, I would like to get the image I want through the do_shortcode based on thumbnail_id. So in person I think the meta_query must disappear/edited because I need to change the way of calling the image. Thanks again for the effort!

Comment: Well actually I can propose an alternative, you will still need the custom query if you wish to loop through your banners and retrieve the meta data. The only thing I don't understand is why you need the shortcode... I mean, is the shortcode going to display every banners in the DB or just the one with the provided ID?

Comment: What are you suggesting? The shortcode_atts is working. If I return it, I'll get the _thumbnail_id of the do_shortcode. Did I need a loop then? Is it not possible to check which thumbnail_id is the same as the one in my database and then echo the value of that record?

Comment: Well I'm trying to understand the way you are going to use the shortcode... Will the shortcode always return only 1 banner? I just want to make sure I get what you are trying to do before I propose the way I'd go about this.

Comment: Yes, the shortcode must always return just one image/banner. It's just a banner plugin where in the end I can easily add a banner on the page I'm creating no matter where I want it. Adding by the shortcode.

So for example; I've got a CPT with all the banners. And when my plugin is active and I want on a specific page an image of Google with the google.com url around it, I only need to call the shortcode with the thumbnail id and get the data out of my wordpress database.

Comment: Ok, one last thing, if the banner image is the featured image of the CPT isn't the thumbnail_id just the ID of that post type?

Comment: I've fixed the problem, I will edit my question so you can see how I've solve the problem.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it working. Good luck with your project :)